# I receive errors after updating bootstrap in my ASP.NET MVC project, I also don't know where the changes take place in my project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-4, bootstrap-4

In content folder - bootstrap.css is showing

- Bootstrap v3.0.0
- Copyright 2013 Twitter, Inc

[This is the view with its default contents visual studio 2015](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YtS3Z.png)

But, after updating to bootstrap v4.5.3 using Nuget package Manager in Visual Studio 2015. The main menu, nav bar and font it has changed.

In content folder - bootstrap.css is showing

- Bootstrap v4.5.3
- Copyright 2011-2020 Twitter, Inc

The issue is I dont know where is that changes take place, is it in CCS, JAVASCRIPT, or where. Also I receive this error "typescript - "error TS1110: Type expected" in index.d.ts file.

[this view is after updating bootstrap v4.5.3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ljfAs.png)

Comment: There's a reason that the version number was bumped from 3 to 4 - Bootstrap 4 is significantly different. You'll probably need to review https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/migration/

Answer (score 0):

There is many differences between Bootstrap 3 and 4.5, so you have to rewrite your code, the class name changed for button for example, but for the menu it's need more changes, the logic is different, also different for modal ..., you can check and copy step by step from their examples.
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/examples/

Be sure to include (in correct order corresponding to your own path) in your page the following ref.:

```
<link href="~/Styles/bootstrap-4.5.3-dist/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap-4.5.3-dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap-4.5.3-dist/js/popper.min.js"></script>
```

you can get them from here : https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/getting-started/download/